# Are there any open source C# libraries for binding the properties from one class to another?

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding

I don't remember which blog I was reading, because it seemed academic at the time, but there was a library being discussed where you could take a two concrete classes and bind the properties together if the names matched. Think ASP.NET MVC model binding.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624823/copy-values-from-one-object-to-another

Comment: Thanks Jason, I think that question complements this one. Voting to leave it open as I was specifically looking for a library and this question has additional tags re: databinding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) which I've used in many projects and would strongly recommend.