# Pass Array to a WCF function

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf

So,  I have a C# project in which, I am loading a XML document (contains name of students and Id) using Linq to xml and I have to get the associated data (their due date, amount and stuff ) from a WCF service. I added the service with just right click and add service reference and now need to pass arrays to the GetData function, which I initialized but its null obviously. I cant able to convert my array to service type and the function returns array too. How do I assign the array to studentArray ?

```
 ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.RycorServiceClient();

Application.ServiceReference1.Student[] studentArray = new ServiceReference1.Student[9];

        Student[] array = studentList.ToArray();

        //for (int i = 0; i <= array.Count(); i++)
        //    studentArray[i] = (RycorApplication.ServiceReference1.Student)array[i];

        //this gives me an error says Cannot convert type 'Application.Student' to 'Application.ServiceReference1.Student'.

        var data = client.GetData(studentArray);
```

After getting this data, how do I save this data to my XML file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much have to do this:

```
List<ServiceReference1.Student> wcfStudentList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ServiceReference1.Student>();
        foreach (var student in studentList)
        {
            wcfStudentList.Add(new ServiceReference1.Student()
            {
                ID = student.ID,
                Name = student.Name,
                ..etc..
            });
        }
        var data = client.GetStudentData(wcfStudentList.ToArray());
```

I do have to question why you don't just change the WCF call if you can to take a List of the student IDs instead of passing the entire object though?

Comment: because, the project i doing, they already gave the service, i did not created the wcf service.

Comment: studentArray is Empty, its just empty array of 9.

Comment: Edited for less confusion (hopefully). Basically, the only way I know here is to iterate over the array of students that you already have and convert each object into the type that the wcf service is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because Application.Student is a different type, you can try to use Application.ServiceReference.Student to save the list of students instead of the "studentList" type.

I suppose that "studentList is an "Application.Student" list and you have to use the same model or make a copy between them using something like this (in the first answer):
[Copy values from one object to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624823/copy-values-from-one-object-to-another)

Comment: List<Student> studentList  is a list of values i loaded from the xml file, in the Student class I created.

Comment: studentArray is empty, i need to pass array of students in getdata funtion in order to get data but student Array is empty rightnow

Comment: The problem is not the content (it's empty). The problem is its type. Try to do it with Application.ServiceReference1.Student[] array = new ServiceReference1.Student[9];

Comment: thats what i am doing, array is Application.ServiceRefrence1.Student[] type, same as studentArray  in my code but what type should be array type in my code.

Comment: No it isn't. Look at array declaration:
Student[] array = studentList.ToArray();
This is a different type than Application.ServiceReference1.Student[].