# how to instantiate child instance from parent instance

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am looking to get a child class instantiated using a parent instance to set all of the inherited variables.

For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    //Variables
}

public class bar : Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public bar(Foo instance)
    {
        base = instance; // Doesn't work but is generally the idea I'm looking for
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a constructor to your parent `Foo` class that accepts a `Foo` instance and takes care of copying the fields.  The `Bar` class can then invoke that as the base constructor.

```
public class Foo
{
    private string var1;
    private string var2;

    public Foo() { }

    public Foo(Foo otherFoo)
    {
        this.var1 = otherFoo.var1;
        this.var2 = otherFoo.var2;
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Bar(Foo instance)
        : base(instance)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make all your members public inside `Foo` that would need to be set from the constructor. Then, set the properties you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you get it done through a public auto property like below. BTW, what you are trying to have is `Composition` wherein `bar` object is composed of `foo` object. Not sure why you are still inheriting from `foo` then?

```
public class bar : Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Foo baseinstance { get; set;} 

    public bar(Foo instance)
    {
        baseinstance = instance; 
    }
}
```

I am not absolutely sure but from your posted code (specifically the below part) it feels like you are trying to call the base class constructor or `constructor initializer` since you said

> I am looking to get a child class instantiated using a parent instance
>   to set all of the inherited variables.

```
public bar(Foo instance)
{
    base = instance; 
}
```

Which should actually be

```
public bar(Foo instance) : base()
{
   //child instance initialization
}
```

But that's not needed for a parameterless constructor cause when you instantiate child object constructor initializer will get invoked and base class will gets initialize first in-order to have the base member initialized before child initialization.

If you have parameterized constructor in base and in child then you can explicitly call base constructor

Comment: I'm using the class as a entity for use with EF6 and afaik EF uses the properties within a class to form a table. A baseinstance would create a seperate table linked by primary and foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for some kind of mapper that maps from one object to another.

You could use a open source project like `AutoMapper` or `ValueInjecter` which can be found on `NuGet`.

Here is also a nice article:
[Copy values from one object to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624823/copy-values-from-one-object-to-another)

Demo with `ValueInjecter`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var foo = new Foo()
    {
        Property1 = "Value1",
        Property2 = "Value2"
    };

    var bar = Mapper.Map<Bar>(foo);
    bar.Id = 3;

    Console.WriteLine(bar.Id); //3
    Console.WriteLine(bar.Property1); //Value1
    Console.WriteLine(bar.Property2); //Value2
}
```