# Compare two properties and set a property based on result

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have the following class:

```
public class CompareField<T>
{
    public CompareField() 
    {
        Status = FieldStatus.NoChange;
    }
    public CompareField(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Status = FieldStatus.NoChange;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
    public FieldStatus Status { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(T objectValue)
    {
        if (!Equals(Value, default(T)) || !Equals(objectValue, default(T))) return false;
        return Value.Equals(objectValue);
    }
}

public enum FieldStatus
{
    NoChange = 0,
    HasChanges = 1
}
```

So my model would contain a bunch of properties, that all use the CompareField type (like CompareField<'string> FirstName {get;set;}...

Now I want to compare two models to eachother and set the FieldStatus of each field, based on the fact that the fields are equal or different.

I've tried using the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986572/hows-to-quick-check-if-data-transfer-two-objects-have-equal-properties-in-c/986617#986617), but it only touches on the comparison part...I can't actually set any properties using that method.

Also, what should I do if T is more complex than just a simple type? Let's say T is a List of classes, what should I use then?

I'm unsure how to implement this (and just using reflection would probably be too slow)...

Any tips would be helpful :)

**EDIT**
So an example would be

---

ModelA

Firstname : Bob

Lastname  : Test

---

ModelB

Firstname : Bobby

Lastname  : Test

---

So I'd like "something" to compare ModelA to ModelB and get the following result

---

ModelA

Firstname : Bob - HasChanges

Lastname  : Test - NoChanges

so by hand it would be something like

```
if (!modelA.FirstName.Value.Equals(modelB.FirstName.Value)) 
    modelA.FirstName.Status = FieldStatus.HasChanges
```

Comment: what property is it you want to set? If it weren't for the generics and reflection, how would you code it by hand, so we can see what you mean? Also: `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(...))` would be a **much** better choice than `Equals(x,y)`, especially if `T` could be a value-type (`int` etc). Comparing lists is **much** more complicated, as you have problems like: same logical values in a different order; item 2 and 3 are removed; how to match that 1==1,2==4,3==5,etc - frankly, that is *really* hard to get right

Comment: for comparing list [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Grundy Thanks, that's going to come in handy!

Comment: @MarcGravell I added an example

Comment: @Team-JoKi you can implement [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx)  interface for your custom classes and simple call `Equals`