# Compare 2 class objects and ignore 1 (or more) property?

Tags: c#, class, if-statement, compare

So I created a class like this:

```
public class ClassName
{
public int ID;

public String n_1 {get; set; }
public String n_2 {get; set; }
// ....
public String n_x {get; set; }
}
```

Later in my code I compare 2 `ClassName` objects:

```
ClassName Item_1 /*...*/ ;
ClassName Item_2 /*...*/ ;
```

Like this:

```
if (Item_1 != Item_2 && Item_1.n_a == Item_2.n_a)
{
//do something
}
```

Now my Problem is that `Item_1.ID` and `Item_2.ID` should be ignored. Is there a easy way to do this? The only solution I came up with is a no brainer of like

```
if ( (Item_1.n_1 != Item_2.n_1 || Item_1.n_2 != Item_2.n_2 || /* ... */ ) && Item_1.n_a == Item_2.n_a)
```

Comment: What's wrong with this? If you're doing manual comparison and you've already ignored `ID` ?

Comment: You should check the [IComparable<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface

Comment: Why not override the Equals method?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: By doing `Item_1 != Item_2`, you will not actually check if all properties from both objects are not equal, it will only check if the references stored inside `Item_1` and `Item_2` are not equal.

Comment: Hi @SeM - Can you explain it to me a little bit more please? I imagined it would compare all the properties in those 2 objects. (Kinda like the no brainer I wrote)

Comment: @axbeit I have added some explanation in answers, you can check it out and if you have questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Override the object.Equals method in your class and specify how you want it to be compared.

Then use `!Item1.Equals(Item2)` instead of `!=`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is what you are actually doing , just create a method like this

```
    public bool Method(ClassName Item_1,ClassName Item2)
    {
    bool check=false;
    if ( (Item_1.n_1 != Item_2.n_1 || Item_1.n_2 != Item_2.n_2 || /* ... */ ) && Item_1.n_a == Item_2.n_a)
    check=true

return check
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2 may be of interest.

Comment: @mjwills hi. The IComparer<T> way seems to be similar to the "no brainer". I still have to write everything manually. Is there an autofill option for it?

Comment: Is there a way to do it less manually? Yes there is. But honestly, it is way more effort (for a once off) than what matteo has suggested here. If you did want to do it the hard way, use https://stackoverflow.com/a/986617/34092 as a starting point @axbeit.

Answer (score 1):

To perform something like `Item_1 != Item_2` or `Item_1 == Item_2` and get all properties (or the ones you want) to be compared, you need to implement your own `Equals` method and `==`, `!=` operators overloads.

`==` operator, from **[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator)**:

> For reference types other than string, == returns true if its two operands refer to the same object.

For that you can start with some straightforward solution, to implement `IEquatable<T>` interface, fill your comparing logic inside `Equals` method  and overload `==` and `!=` operators internally calling your type-safe `Equals` method:

```
public class ClassName : IEquatable<ClassName>
{
    public int ID;

    public String n_1 { get; set; }
    public String n_2 { get; set; }
    // ....
    public String n_x { get; set; }

    public static bool operator ==(ClassName obj1, ClassName obj2)
    {
        if (((object)obj1) == null || ((object)obj2) == null)
            return Equals(obj1, obj2);
        return obj1.Equals(obj2);
    }

    public static bool operator != (ClassName obj1, ClassName obj2)
    {
        if (((object)obj1) == null || ((object)obj2) == null)
            return !Equals(obj1, obj2);
        return !obj1.Equals(obj2);
    }


    public bool Equals(ClassName obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;

        return (n_1 == obj.n_1) && (n_2 == obj.n_2) && (n_x == obj.n_x); //you can ignore ID here
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        ClassName classNameObj = obj as ClassName;
        if (classNameObj == null)
            return false;
        else
            return Equals(classNameObj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //This code was generated by VS ide, you can write your own hashing logic
        var hashCode = 1032198799;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + ID.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(n_1);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(n_2);
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(n_x);
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Then you can check in your `if`:

```
if (Item_1 != Item_2)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

For `Equals` method you should stick to **[Guidelines for Overriding Equals() and Operator ==](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms173147(v=vs.90))** .

References: **[== Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator)**, **[!= Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/not-equal-operator)**, **[IEquatable Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)**, **[IEquatable.Equals(T) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2)**, **[Guidelines for Overriding Equals() and Operator ==](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms173147(v=vs.90))**