# How can I update only the modified fields of the object in mongodb using C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to update only the modified fields of the object in the DB
Suppose the exising object in db is -

```
User user = new User(){
  Name = "Sid",
  Age = 20,
  Gender = "Male" 
}
```

and after modification it looks like this -

```
User user = new User(){
  Name = "Siddhant",
  Age = 20,
  Gender = "Male" 
}
```

Now only one field is changed that is Name, how can I run a query so that only the changes get updated in
DB.

Also, the User class in the above example could be more complex like it will have properties of user-defined data types as well.

Comment: Write a [`helper method`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986572/how-to-quickly-check-if-two-data-transfer-objects-have-equal-properties-in-c/986617) that checks this 2 objects which properties have changed via reflection and construct the update query based on that

Comment: Why not just update all the fields? are you worried about the overhead?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @KunalMukherjee . I have tried exactly the same thing and it works also, but there is a limitation like what if the object becomes more complex and has deeply nested properties. So I'm not sure whether this is a correct approach or not!

Comment: @TomSlabbaert Right because it may contain many properties even nested classes