# AmbiguousMatchException with double property in derived class inheriting from IComparable property in base class

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get the properties of a type, without knowing the types of the property in advance by calling Type.GetProperty("typename").

It's throwing an AmbiguousMatchException because it finds two properties, one declared as IComparable in a base class, and a double in a derived class.

I'm not a .NET pro by any means, but I would've expected such an exception if both properties had different concrete types, rather than one declared in terms of an interface and another having a concrete type. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

I guess the solution is the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443763/1491101) question.