# Finding property differences between two C# objects

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, auditing

The project I'm working on needs some simple audit logging for when a user changes their email, billing address, etc.  The objects we're working with are coming from different sources, one a WCF service, the other a web service.

I've implemented the following method using reflection to find changes to the properties on two different objects.  This generates a list of the properties that have differences along with their old and new values.

```
public static IList GenerateAuditLogMessages(T originalObject, T changedObject)
{
    IList list = new List();
    string className = string.Concat("[", originalObject.GetType().Name, "] ");

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in originalObject.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        Type comparable =
            property.PropertyType.GetInterface("System.IComparable");

        if (comparable != null)
        {
            string originalPropertyValue =
                property.GetValue(originalObject, null) as string;
            string newPropertyValue =
                property.GetValue(changedObject, null) as string;

            if (originalPropertyValue != newPropertyValue)
            {
                list.Add(string.Concat(className, property.Name,
                    " changed from '", originalPropertyValue,
                    "' to '", newPropertyValue, "'"));
            }
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

I'm looking for System.IComparable because "All numeric types (such as Int32 and Double) implement IComparable, as do String, Char, and DateTime."  This seemed the best way to find any property that's not a custom class.

Tapping into the PropertyChanged event that's generated by the WCF or web service proxy code sounded good but doesn't give me enough info for my audit logs (old and new values).

Looking for input as to if there is a better way to do this, thanks!

@Aaronaught, here is some example code that is generating a positive match based on doing object.Equals:

```
Address address1 = new Address();
address1.StateProvince = new StateProvince();

Address address2 = new Address();
address2.StateProvince = new StateProvince();

IList list = Utility.GenerateAuditLogMessages(address1, address2);
```

> "[Address] StateProvince changed from
>   'MyAccountService.StateProvince' to
>   'MyAccountService.StateProvince'"

It's two different instances of the StateProvince class, but the values of the properties are the same (all null in this case).  We're not overriding the equals method.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`IComparable` is for ordering comparisons.  Either use `IEquatable` instead, or just use the static `System.Object.Equals` method.  The latter has the benefit of also working if the object is not a primitive type but still defines its own equality comparison by overriding `Equals`.

```
object originalValue = property.GetValue(originalObject, null);
object newValue = property.GetValue(changedObject, null);
if (!object.Equals(originalValue, newValue))
{
    string originalText = (originalValue != null) ?
        originalValue.ToString() : "[NULL]";
    string newText = (newText != null) ?
        newValue.ToString() : "[NULL]";
    // etc.
}
```

This obviously isn't perfect, but if you're only doing it with classes that you control, then you can make sure it always works for your particular needs.

There are other methods to compare objects (such as checksums, serialization, etc.) but this is probably the most reliable if the classes don't consistently implement `IPropertyChanged` and you want to actually know the differences.

---

Update for new example code:

```
Address address1 = new Address();
address1.StateProvince = new StateProvince();

Address address2 = new Address();
address2.StateProvince = new StateProvince();

IList list = Utility.GenerateAuditLogMessages(address1, address2);
```

The reason that using `object.Equals` in your audit method results in a "hit" is because the instances are actually not equal!

Sure, the `StateProvince` may be empty in both cases, but `address1` and `address2` still have non-null values for the `StateProvince` property and each instance is different.  Therefore, `address1` and `address2` have different properties.

Let's flip this around, take this code as an example:

```
Address address1 = new Address("35 Elm St");
address1.StateProvince = new StateProvince("TX");

Address address2 = new Address("35 Elm St");
address2.StateProvince = new StateProvince("AZ");
```

Should these be considered equal?  Well, they will be, using your method, because `StateProvince` does not implement `IComparable`.  That's the only reason why your method reported that the two objects were the same in the original case.  Since the `StateProvince` class does not implement `IComparable`, the tracker just skips that property entirely.  But these two addresses are clearly not equal!

This is why I originally suggested using `object.Equals`, because then you can override it in the `StateProvince` method to get better results:

```
public class StateProvince
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        StateProvince sp = obj as StateProvince;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(sp, null))
            return false;

        return (sp.Code == Code);
    }

    public bool Equals(StateProvince sp)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(sp, null))
            return false;

        return (sp.Code == Code);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Code.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Code: [{0}]", Code);
    }
}
```

Once you've done this, the `object.Equals` code will work perfectly.  Instead of naïvely checking whether or not `address1` and `address2` literally have the same `StateProvince` reference, it will actually check for semantic equality.

---

The other way around this is to extend the tracking code to actually descend into sub-objects.  In other words, for each property, check the `Type.IsClass` and optionally the `Type.IsInterface` property, and if `true`, then recursively invoke the change-tracking method on the property itself, prefixing any audit results returned recursively with the property name.  So you'd end up with a change for `StateProvinceCode`.

I use the above approach sometimes too, but it's easier to just override `Equals` on the objects for which you want to compare semantic equality (i.e. audit) and provide an appropriate `ToString` override that makes it clear what changed.  It doesn't scale for deep nesting but I think it's unusual to want to audit that way.

The last trick is to define your own interface, say `IAuditable<T>`, which takes a second instance of the same type as a parameter and actually returns a list (or enumerable) of all of the differences.  It's similar to our overridden `object.Equals` method above but gives back more information.  This is useful for when the object graph is really complicated and you know you can't rely on Reflection or `Equals`.  You can combine this with the above approach; really all you have to do is substitute `IComparable` for your `IAuditable` and invoke the `Audit` method if it implements that interface.

Comment: Unfortunately using just object.Equals is returning true for reference types, for example:

[Address] StateProvince changed from 'MyAccountService.StateProvince' to 'MyAccountService.StateProvince'

Comment: @Pete Nelson: Assuming you're actually comparing different references, that's... improbable.  Can we see a complete example with the class?  Does it override the `Equals` method?  I use code very similar to this and it never gives false negatives.

Comment: Added an example of the match to the original post.

Comment: This is definitely a workable solution for most situations.  However, we're working with WCF and web service proxy classes, so implementing interfaces or overriding equals isn't quite as straightforward.  Since the generated proxy classes are declared as partial classes and we can tack on additional code, it's not impossible.

I'm definitely going to check out the Type.IsClass property though and see if I want to go down that rabbit hole in comparing the whole object graph.

Comment: You may change the line `string newText = (newText != null) ?` to `string newText = (newValue != null) ?` as it does not compile.

Answer (score 21):

[This](https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects) project on github checks nearly any type of property and can be customized as you need.

Comment: From some cursory testing, this also looks pretty good.  At the very least, their source code is giving me more information on how they're doing their object comparison.

Comment: Here's another one that uses expression trees. Probably faster. https://github.com/StevenGilligan/AutoCompare

Answer (score 11):

You might want to look at [Microsoft's Testapi](http://testapi.codeplex.com/) It has an object comparison api that does deep comparisons. It might be overkill for you but it could be worth a look.

```
var comparer = new ObjectComparer(new PublicPropertyObjectGraphFactory());
IEnumerable<ObjectComparisonMismatch> mismatches;
bool result = comparer.Compare(left, right, out mismatches);

foreach (var mismatch in mismatches)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("\t'{0}' = '{1}' and '{2}'='{3}' do not match. '{4}'",
        mismatch.LeftObjectNode.Name, mismatch.LeftObjectNode.ObjectValue,
        mismatch.RightObjectNode.Name, mismatch.RightObjectNode.ObjectValue,
        mismatch.MismatchType);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a short LINQ version that extends object and returns a list of properties that are not equal:

usage: `object.DetailedCompare(objectToCompare);`

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static List<Variance> DetailedCompare<T>(this T val1, T val2)
    {
        var propertyInfo = val1.GetType().GetProperties();
        return propertyInfo.Select(f => new Variance
            {
                Property = f.Name,
                ValueA = f.GetValue(val1),
                ValueB = f.GetValue(val2)
            })
            .Where(v => !v.ValueA.Equals(v.ValueB))
            .ToList();
    }

    public class Variance
    {
        public string Property { get; set; }
        public object ValueA { get; set; }
        public object ValueB { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: This only works for base property types. Lists of child objects will always report as different even if they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

You never want to implement `GetHashCode` on mutable properties (properties that could be changed by someone) - i.e. non-private setters.

Imagine this scenario:

1. you put an instance of your object in a collection which uses `GetHashCode()` "under the covers" or directly (Hashtable).
2. Then someone changes the value of the field/property that you've used in your `GetHashCode()` implementation.

Guess what... your object is permanently lost in the collection since the collection uses `GetHashCode()` to find it! You've effectively changed the hashcode value from what was originally placed in the collection. Probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

[Liviu Trifoi solution:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5823459/5697765) Using CompareNETObjects library.
[GitHub](https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects) - [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CompareNETObjects) - [Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/754435/Compare-NET-Objects-Tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is quite neat, it avoids repetition or adding anything to classes. What more are you looking for?

The only alternative would be to generate a state dictionary for the old and new objects, and write a comparison for them. The code for generating the state dictionary could reuse any serialisation you have for storing this data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The my way of `Expression` tree compile version. It should faster than `PropertyInfo.GetValue`.

```
static class ObjDiffCollector<T>
{
    private delegate DiffEntry DiffDelegate(T x, T y);

    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, DiffDelegate> DicDiffDels;

    private static PropertyInfo PropertyOf<TClass, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> selector)
        => (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)selector.Body).Member;

    static ObjDiffCollector()
    {
        var expParamX = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var expParamY = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "y");

        var propDrName = PropertyOf((DiffEntry x) => x.Prop);
        var propDrValX = PropertyOf((DiffEntry x) => x.ValX);
        var propDrValY = PropertyOf((DiffEntry x) => x.ValY);

        var dic = new Dictionary<string, DiffDelegate>();

        var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (var info in props)
        {
            var expValX = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(expParamX, info);
            var expValY = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(expParamY, info);

            var expEq = Expression.Equal(expValX, expValY);

            var expNewEntry = Expression.New(typeof(DiffEntry));
            var expMemberInitEntry = Expression.MemberInit(expNewEntry,
                Expression.Bind(propDrName, Expression.Constant(info.Name)),
                Expression.Bind(propDrValX, Expression.Convert(expValX, typeof(object))),
                Expression.Bind(propDrValY, Expression.Convert(expValY, typeof(object)))
            );

            var expReturn = Expression.Condition(expEq
                , Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(null), typeof(DiffEntry))
                , expMemberInitEntry);

            var expLambda = Expression.Lambda<DiffDelegate>(expReturn, expParamX, expParamY);

            var compiled = expLambda.Compile();

            dic[info.Name] = compiled;
        }

        DicDiffDels = dic;
    }

    public static DiffEntry[] Diff(T x, T y)
    {
        var list = new List<DiffEntry>(DicDiffDels.Count);
        foreach (var pair in DicDiffDels)
        {
            var r = pair.Value(x, y);
            if (r != null) list.Add(r);
        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }
}

class DiffEntry
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
    public object ValX { get; set; }
    public object ValY { get; set; }
}
```