# Serialize Linq2Sql Object After Dispose

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-sql, serialization, datacontext

I'm trying to find a simple way to serialize any object so that only the *immediate* properties and their "ToString" values are included. In the case of an object coming from a DataContext I want to be able to ignore properties of properties (ie. if a property is a complex object, don't serialize that object as well). This is especially important if the properties are not loaded since it causes an error "Cannot access an object after it has been disposed"...

I created the following but it fails when it tries to access a property that wasn't loaded in the original datacontext call.

```
string typeString = o.GetType().Name;
        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
        xml.AppendFormat("<{0}>\r\n", typeString);

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in o.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var propertyValue = property.GetValue(o, null);
            if (property.GetType() != typeof(System.Data.Linq.Binary) && property.PropertyType.Name != "EntitySet`1" && property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlIgnoreAttribute), true).Count() == 0)
            {
                xml.AppendFormat("<{0}>{1}</{0}>\r\n", property.Name, propertyValue);
            }

        }

        xml.AppendFormat("</{0}>", typeString);

        return xml.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a stock serializer with appropriate "ignore" attributes, e.g. use [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) and the [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx) on properties you do not wish to have serialized.

If you wish to stick with the approach you outline, you can check  [PropertyInfo.PropertyType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype.aspx) to not act on anything that is a complex type.

You can use [Type.IsPrimitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) to see if a given type is primitive or not, but there are a few gotcha's that are well-covered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2442544/141172

Comment: I want to avoid tagging classes with "IgnoreDataMember". Essentially I want a snapshot of the object I pass to it so how would I go about using the PropertyType to filter out "complex types", would I need to say where type = int, or string, or.. etc?

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: This is great. It fixes the datacontext issue too, although ideally I could still have "loaded" properties that are complex types show up using "ToString". But I'll take what I can get.