# Reflection GetProperties should exclude unwanted children properties on certain datatype

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Surely I am missing the obvious.I am building an internal application and I am reflecting on some of our internal dlls and displaying them in a tree view

Treeview is loaded on demand and for each property when expanded I get the children if any.
When children are datetime,string,decimal etc.. I then are expanded once again
I should not be getting all the inner properties of a string or datetime and so on . It should not return anything.I have tried few bindingFlags but we no success.

I am using the following method but it's not good enough.

```
  public static PropertyInfo[] GetPropertiesByType(this Type t)
    {
        if (!t.IsPrimitive
            || t != typeof (System.Decimal)
            || t != typeof (System.String)
              || t != typeof(System.DateTime)
            || t != typeof (System.DateTime?))
        {

            return t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToArray();
        }
        return new PropertyInfo[0];
    }
```

What I want is that when getting Properties it should exclude all the inner properties that a not relevant.

EG
Customer has order and order has OrderedDate.When using the treeview I click on customer and 
I get order click on order and I get OrderDate when clicking orderdate I should have no properties.I get "HasValue and value" and expand value and get all the datetime stuff.

Same when a property is a string I should not see Chars and Length.

Any suggestions

Comment: So you practically want to exclude any property that is a native CLR type? string (String), int (Int32) etc?

Comment: @Abhinav yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!t.IsPrimitive
    || t != typeof (System.Decimal)
    || t != typeof (System.String)
    || t != typeof(System.DateTime)
    || t != typeof (System.DateTime?))
```

should be

```
if (!t.IsPrimitive
    && t != typeof (System.Decimal)
    && t != typeof (System.String)
    && t != typeof(System.DateTime)
    && t != typeof (System.DateTime?))
```

As is, your conditional will always evaluate to true since all types are either not `System.String` or not `System.Decimal` and you are combining them with the OR operator.

Comment: hi,That is seeems to work! how do you detect nullable bool as bool? does not seem to be detected.

Comment: @user231465 If you are getting the parameter Type t from a call to GetType(), you shouldn't need to detect nullable bool (calling GetType() on a bool? should return typeof(bool)). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx. If this solves your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: @DerekJS Begging for fame? :)

Comment: @Bogdan I just got enough to comment yesterday, so for the moment, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

you should manually check for primitive types and return an empty array. you can check that with the answer to the wuestion here [How To Test if Type is Primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442534/how-to-test-if-type-is-primitive)

```
if (t.IsPrimitive || t == typeof(Decimal) || t == typeof(String) || ... )
{
    // Is Primitive, or Decimal, or String
}
```

so basically you can do

```
public static PropertyInfo[] GetPropertiesByType(this Type t)
    {
        if (t.IsPrimitive || t == typeof(Decimal) || t == typeof(String) || ... )
    {
        return //empty array
    }
        return t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToArray();
    }
```

-Update

```
public static PropertyInfo[] GetPropertiesByType(this Type t)
    {
        if (!t.IsPrimitive
            || t != typeof (System.Decimal)
            || t != typeof (System.String)
            || t != typeof(System.DateTime)
            || t != typeof (System.DateTime?))
        {

            return t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToArray();
        }
        else
        return new PropertyInfo[0];
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply tried the following but still not working. See updated question code snippet

Comment: have your tried the code sample i have just added it is not entirely same to what you have done

Comment: Yes I did.the only difference and was a typo was !t.IsPrimitive

Comment: on what type now are still the members being populated?

Answer (score 1):

Before expanding you should check Type.FullName property and do not expand if type it is not in your namespaces.

To elaborate a little, the following code from MSDN illustrates what FullName does:

```
Type t = typeof(Array);
Console.WriteLine("The full name of the Array type is {0}.", t.FullName);

/* This example produces the following output:

The full name of the Array type is System.Array.
*/
```

You can test for example if FullName starts with "System." or "Microsoft." and do not expand those properties.

Comment: Hi thanks for your time. Can you elaborate a bit not sure i understand

Answer (score 0):

May be:

```
    public static PropertyInfo[] GetPropertiesByType(this Type t)
    {
        if (!typeof (MyBasePropertyClass).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            return new PropertyInfo[0];

        return t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                .ToArray();
    }
```

where MyBasePropertyClass is a base class for your entities.