# C# check if type of PropertyInfo is primitive

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Is it possible to check if the type, which is stored in `PropertyInfo`, is primitive?

For example I want to do this:

```
 // from and to are both objects declared in the parameters.
 Type fType = from.GetType();
 Type tType = to.GetType();

 PropertyInfo[] fmpi = fType.GetProperties();
 PropertyInfo[] tmpi = tType.GetProperties();

 foreach(var pi in  tmpi)
 {
     if (pi.CanWrite)
     {
         var fpi = fmpi.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Name.ToLower() == pi.Name.ToLower());

         if (pi.GetType().IsPrimitive || pi.GetType() == typeof(string))
         {
             pi.SetValue(to, fpi.GetValue(from, null));
         }
     }
 }
```

Whenever I execute this code It doesn't go through the `if` statemenet. The main reason is that whenever I do `pi.GetType()` it says that it's a `PropertyInfo`. This is quite obvious since it's declared as a `PropertyInfo`. But I hope you get the idea.

I have also discovered that `pi.PropertyType.Name` contains the name of the actual type of the property. Is there anyway I can execute `IsPrimitive` on this property? If not, is there any work around which let's me do something like this?

I checked out [How To Test if Type is Primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442534/how-to-test-if-type-is-primitive) but in this situation the user is using a direct type and I'm using `PropertyInfo`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Test if Type is Primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442534/how-to-test-if-type-is-primitive)

Comment: No it is not, since I'm using PropertyInfo not a direct type

Comment: @B.Hulsof did you refer to all answer in that page?

Comment: what is your definition of primitive first, as people have all sorts of misconceptions here

Comment: Yes I did, this question is something slightly different

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The main reason is that whenever I do pi.GetType() it says that it's a PropertyInfo.

You should use [`PropertyType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `PropertyInfo` instead of using `GetType()` method.

Excerpt from documentation:

> Gets the type of this property.

So instead of

```
pi.GetType().IsPrimitive
```

use this

```
pi.PropertyType.IsPrimitive
```