# Comparing Object properties using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I have two classes Address and Employee as follows:

```
 public class Address
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}

   public class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Address EmployeeAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

I have two employee instances as follows:

```
    var emp1Address = new Address();
    emp1Address.AddressLine1 = "Microsoft Corporation";
    emp1Address.AddressLine2 = "One Microsoft Way";
    emp1Address.City = "Redmond";
    emp1Address.State = "WA";
    emp1Address.Zip = "98052-6399";

    var emp1 = new Employee();
    emp1.FirstName = "Bill";
    emp1.LastName = "Gates";
    emp1.EmployeeAddress = emp1Address;


    var emp2Address = new Address();
    emp2Address.AddressLine1 = "Gates Foundation";
    emp2Address.AddressLine2 = "One Microsoft Way";
    emp2Address.City = "Redmond";
    emp2Address.State = "WA";
    emp2Address.Zip = "98052-6399";

    var emp2 = new Employee();
    emp2.FirstName = "Melinda";
    emp2.LastName = "Gates";
    emp2.EmployeeAddress = emp2Address;
```

Now how can I write a method which compares these two employees and returns the list of properties which have different values. So in this example I would like the result to be FirstName and Address.AddressLine1 .

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing object properties in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506096/comparing-object-properties-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You don't necessarily need reflection to perform the comparison.** You can write a comparer class that takes two instances of Employee or Address, and compares each field that should match. For any that don't match, you can add a string (or `PropertyInfo`) element to some list to return to the caller.

Whether you return a `PropertyInfo`, `MemberInfo`, or just a string depends on what the caller needs to do with the result. If you actually need to visit the fields that contain differences, the `PropertyInfo/MemberInfo` may be better - but to just report the differences a string is probaby sufficient.

The main value of reflection would be to write a *general purpose* object comparer that could take two instances of *any kind of object* and compare their public fields and properties. This helps avoid writing repetetive comparison code over and over - but that doesn't seem like the case you're in.

Answer (score 28):

Like LBushskin said, you do not have to do this. This is not the fastest way! Buy if you want, try this:

```
    public static List<PropertyInfo> GetDifferences(Employee test1, Employee test2)
    {
        List<PropertyInfo> differences = new List<PropertyInfo>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in test1.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            object value1 = property.GetValue(test1, null);
            object value2 = property.GetValue(test2, null);
            if (!value1.Equals(value2))
            {
                differences.Add(property);
            }
        }
        return differences;
    }
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but for lists, it wouldn't result correct results sometimes if capacity parameter is different even though list entities and counts are equal

Comment: if value2 was changed to null this will cause nullreference

Answer (score 7):

Here is a generic and recursive solution based on Oskar Kjellin's [awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2502468/).

I have posted this code as [gist](https://gist.github.com/MiroslavMikus/8d8ebb9b89d033ff996dc0908f13b19e) as well, so you can check the latest version or star/clone/fork it :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

protected List<KeyValuePair<Type, PropertyInfo>> RecrusiveReflectionCompare<T>(T first, T second)
        where T : class
    {
        var differences = new List<KeyValuePair<Type, PropertyInfo>>();

        var parentType = first.GetType();

        void CompareObject(object obj1, object obj2, PropertyInfo info)
        {
            if (!obj1.Equals(obj2))
            {
                differences.Add(new KeyValuePair<Type, PropertyInfo>(parentType, info));
            }
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in parentType.GetProperties())
        {
            object value1 = property.GetValue(first, null);
            object value2 = property.GetValue(second, null);

            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value1 as string) != string.IsNullOrEmpty(value2 as string))
                {
                    CompareObject(value1, value2, property);
                }
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive)
            {
                CompareObject(value1, value2, property);
            }
            else
            {
                if (value1 == null && value2 == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                differences.Concat(RecrusiveReflectionCompare(value1, value2));
            }
        }
        return differences;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetNotEqualsProperties(Employee emp1, Employee emp2)
{
    Type employeeType = typeof (Employee);
    var properies = employeeType.GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properies)
        if(!property.GetValue(emp1, null).Equals(property.GetValue(emp2, null))) //TODO: check for null
            yield return property;
}
```

And for complex properties you have to override Equals method

```
public class Address
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj as Address == null)
            return false;
        return ((Address) obj).AddressLine1.Equals(AddressLine1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No need for reflection. Of course, this example is returning a string with the property names...if you need the actual `PropertyInfo` object, things would get a little more difficult, but not by much.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> DiffEmployees
    (Employee one, Employee two)
{
    if(one.FirstName != two.FirstName)
        yield return "FirstName";
    if(one.LastName != two.LastName)
        yield return "LastName";
    if(one.Address.AddressLine1 != two.Address.AddressLine1)
        yield return "Address.AddressLine1";

    // And so on.
}
```

Comment: He specifically asked for a solution using reflection, and prob avoid doing it manually as you suggest.

Comment: If you add or remove a property to the object, you'll have to manually update this each time. Manually also gets long and complicated quickly for objects with plenty of properties

Comment: Using reflection means you can make it generic. Things get complex fast with all the different types and nullable types, writing a generic comparer gets complex if you're handling all type permutations and casting, which is why I'm here.