# How determinate if Json that I receive is blank

Tags: c#, json, null

I have a function that receive a JObject, and in one case the Json that I receive are this:

```
{}
```

and I was trying to manage with this:

```
 public void GetSomeJson(JObject request)
    {
          if (request==JObject.Parse("{}"))
              throw new ArgumentNullException("The request are null");
          //more stuff
    }
```

In this way doesn't work, and jump the condition, any idea to recognize the Json received is null or blank?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436299/comparing-objects)

Comment: This is not a duplicate (of that particular question, anyway). The answers to that question will not help OP with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JObject` is a container for properties and implements `IDictionary<string, JToken>` to access them, so this would test if an object has zero properties:

```
if (request.Count == 0) { /* The object is empty */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void GetSomeJson(JObject request)
    {
            if ( request != null && request.Count == 0 ) 
              throw new ArgumentNullException("The request are null");

    }
```

Comment: Please either edit this to make it a complete answer or make it a comment on another answer.

Comment: `ArgumentNullException` doesn't make sense when the object is empty but not null.  Maybe `ArgumentException`, but if the object isn't null then ANE is not appropriate.

Comment: sure you can add couple of more lines :)