# How to compare two instances' contents in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, compare, equals

I have a silly question here.
I define a class with many data members, like this:

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }
    //...many members
    public C Direction { get; set; }
    public List<B> NameValue1 { get; set; }
    public List<string> NameValue2 { get; set; }
    //...many members
}
```

Now, I'm writing unit test code and want to compare two instances of class A.
But I found this doesn't work:

```
Assert.AreEquals(a1, a2);
```

I must override `Equals` method to do that? C# can't help with this by default?
Or I can serialize these two guys and compare the filestream?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on what kind of comparison you want. The default Equals just compare the two instances and not its contents. Override and compare each and every item.

Comment: @zenwalker you'd better post your comment as an answer

Comment: @Arseny
Its not really an answer the OP is looking for i guess. Plus do not like getting downvoted too :D

Comment: You may use reflection to compare value type properties, but for reference type properties this does not work. Also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506096/comparing-object-properties-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default equality implementation, for reference types, is reference equality: "is this the same instance". For equivalence, yes, you should write that yourself if you need that, but: it is rarely all that useful really (and there's a problem, because if you override `Equals` you should override `GetHashCode` too, with a suitably parallel implementation.

Personally, I'd compare manually in your unit test if this code isn't part of your main system.

Lists are a pain too, since there are three options:

- same list instance
- different lists with same content instances
- different lists with *equivalent* content instances

You probably mean the last, but that is the same problem, repeated.

Re serialization: that is tricky too, since it depends on the serializer and the contents. I wouldn't recommend that route unless a: your type is already being used for serialization, and b: your chosen serializer guarantees the semantic you mean. For example, `BinaryFormatter` **does not** (I can provide a concrete example if you want, but trust me: this is not guaranteed).

Comment: It is just a thought in my mind: serializer can deal with my custom class recursively, so there must be a "comparer" to do it in the same way. OK. I'm interested in your example about BinaryFormatter. Thank you.