# Query to detect duplicate rows

Tags: c#, .net, linq, duplicates

I had read data from an XML file into DataSet by using c# than I want to identify duplicate (completely the same ) rows in that set.
I tried such kind of grouping and that works!

```
var d= from r1 in table.AsEnumerable()
       group r1 by new
       {
            t0 = r1[0],
            t1 = r1[1],
            t2 = r1[2],
            t3 = r1[3],
            t4 = r1[4],
            t5 = r1[5],
            t6 = r1[6],
            t7 = r1[7],
            t8 = r1[8],
       }
       into grp
       where grp.Count() > 1
       select grp;
```

But the number of data columns can be differ, so I cannot apply static grouping in query like above. I had to generate the grouping array dynamically?

**I don't want to delete dublicate, I just want to find them!**

Comment: What you are looking for is a way to compare all properties of an instance. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506096/comparing-object-properties-in-c-sharp

Comment: there is no primary key!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var rows = table.AsEnumerable();
var unique = rows.Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default);
var duplicates = rows.Except(unique); // , DataRowComparer.Default);
```

Comment: @CuongLe: Will this not filter out duplicate rows using `EqualityComparer<DataRow>.Default` which compared all row's columns?

Comment: No, DataRow is not like anonymous class, not structural type

Comment: @CuongLe: okay, use `DataRowComparer.Default` then.

Comment: The `duplicates` collection is always empty because the same comparer that is used to detect duplicates, removes all the occurances of that duplicate row (no only the first one).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
DataTable dt = TableName;
dt = oPerformance.RemoveDuplicateRows(dt, ColToCompareAndRemove);
```

and here is the function RemoveDuplicateRows

```
public DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dTable, string colName)
        {
            Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
            ArrayList duplicateList = new ArrayList();

            //Add list of all the unique item value to hashtable, which stores combination of key, value pair.
            //And add duplicate item value in arraylist.
            foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
            {
                if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName]))
                    duplicateList.Add(drow);
                else
                    hTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty);
            }

            //Removing a list of duplicate items from datatable.
            foreach (DataRow dRow in duplicateList)
                dTable.Rows.Remove(dRow);

            //Datatable which contains unique records will be return as output.
            return dTable;
        }
```

Comment: Use `List<>` and `Dictionary<,>` instead. Are you aware about generics' benefits?