# Comparing two unknown type object

Tags: c#, reflection, equals

Here is the situation. I have two unknown type's objects that i would like to compare to know if one is identical to another. Both can be string, int, enumerable or any custom class you can imagine. Is there a way to achieve this using reflection ?

Thanks !

Comment: They should be, if they are not, i would say they aren't equal

Comment: Could you use the [is keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.71).aspx)? Could you maybe do `if (a is b)`? I don't know if this works off the top of my head, worth a try though

Comment: Why do you need "using reflection"? Servy's answer (+1) shows how to do that without reflection. Or you want manually compare each field of both objects via reflection (dangerous idea IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

You use the `Equals` method from object, in the general case.

```
object first = GetFirst();
object second = GetSecond();

bool areEqual = object.Equals(first, second);
```

Another option when writing a particular function (often a generic function) that needs to compare types not known at compile time is to accept an `IEqualityComparer`, so that if the type doesn't have an implementation of `Equals` that's appropriate in context the caller of your method (or user of your type, if it's for the whole class) can provide their own implementation.  A good example of this is a method such as `string.Contains`.  There is an optional overload that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<char>` that lets the caller define what it means for two characters to be equal.

Comment: this will not work, i can't compare two objects of a custom type by using the object class equals method..

Comment: @user2161442 Sure you can, if the class uses a sensible `Equals` implementation (which objects that you would expect to be compared in this manor should do).  If it doesn't have one, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

If your class overrides `Equals`, use Servy's approach. Otherwise, you can use [CompareNetObjects](http://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com) library (available on nuget).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/844855/1009661) is an example of comparing two objects by their public properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.ReferenceEquals` and `GetType`

Example pulled from MSDN:

```
int n1 = 12;
int n2 = 82;
long n3 = 12;

Console.WriteLine("n1 and n2 are the same type: {0}",
                  Object.ReferenceEquals(n1.GetType(), n2.GetType()));
Console.WriteLine("n1 and n3 are the same type: {0}",
                  Object.ReferenceEquals(n1.GetType(), n3.GetType()));
// The example displays the following output: 
//       n1 and n2 are the same type: True 
//       n1 and n3 are the same type: False
```

Source:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx

I may have misunderstood, however. This will check only check to see if they are the same type, two objects of the same type with different references will still evaluate to `true` using this method.