# PropertyInfo.GetValue unable to compare datetimes?

Tags: c#

I am looping through two objects to see if all items within the two objects are the same.  After adding a watch at the point where it is return false, I see the same values.  The two items being compared are both datetime.  They have the exact same value, but are returning false.  My question is **Considering these two items are both datetime, are they causing the issue?  If not, is there a better way to compare my two objects?**

```
private bool CompareObj(Visit object1, Visit object2)
{
    foreach (var obj1PropertyInfo in object1.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        foreach (var obj2PropertyInfo in object2.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (obj1PropertyInfo.Name == obj2PropertyInfo.Name && obj1PropertyInfo.GetValue(object1, null) != obj2PropertyInfo.GetValue(object2, null))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do they actually have the same value, including ticks/milliseconds?

Comment: Use `.Equals`, not `==`. Otherwise you are comparing references of boxed DateTime values instead of the values themselves.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin - Yes, they do have the same value.

Comment: And are they identical references?

Comment: Also you don't need nested loop. It can be only one..

Comment: What was the purpose of this? Would object.Equals(object1, object2) fit? Why not? Can they have different type? What if one have property that the other does not have?

Comment: There may be simmilar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506096/comparing-object-properties-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Equals (works for nulls as well)

```
private bool CompareObj(Visit object1, Visit object2)
{
    foreach (var obj1PropertyInfo in object1.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        foreach (var obj2PropertyInfo in object2.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (obj1PropertyInfo.Name == obj2PropertyInfo.Name
            && !Equals(obj1PropertyInfo.GetValue(object1, null),
            obj2PropertyInfo.GetValue(object2, null)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Also you can eliminate nested loop. It is redundant

Comment: Can be reduced if object1.GetType() == object2.GetType() ...but can we assume that? Or can we return false if the type is different?

Comment: Can be reduced to `return object.Equals(object1, object2);`.  If the types aren't the same, then the objects won't be either.

Comment: Object can be equal even if not of the same type. We need to know what was the purpose first.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a linq way:

```
return object1
      .GetType()
      .GetProperties()
      .All(x => object.Equals(x.GetValue(object1), x.GetValue(object2));
```

Comment: What if I pass in some object with a property with value null?

Comment: Then you get a `NullReferenceException`, obviously, as this was originally written.  `object.Equals` fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Michael Lieu for suggesting this first, but I will put it in answer form since he did not.

If you are only interested in object equality (and not whether or not the objects share the same reference), use the `.Equals` method.  By default (i.e., assuming that it is not overloaded), `==` compares references, which (presumably) are the same in your case because these are 2 different instances of `DateTime`.

This is all under the assumption that you are comparing 2 `DateTime` instances, of course: 
    private bool CompareObj(Visit object1, Visit object2)
    {
        return object.Equals(object1, object2);
    }

If you are comparing more complex objects, you may need the loop with reflection to iterate through the properties.

Summary:  If you are only interested in equality, but you don't care whether or not the references are identical, use `Equals` instead of `==`.