# FluentAssertions; combining collection and object graph comparison assertions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I am trying to use FluentAssertions to combine collection and object graph comparison assertions.

I have the following class.

```
public class Contract
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which are returned in a collection, like so.

```
ICollection<Contract> contracts = factory.BuildContracts();
```

I then want to make sure that collection contains only specific `Contract` objects.

```
contracts.Should().Contain(new Contract() { Id = id1, Name = "A" });
```

This doesn't work, I'm believe because `Contain` is using `object.Equals` rather than object graph comparison, (as provided by `ShouldBeEquivalentTo`).

I also need to assert that the collection doesn't contain a specific object, i.e.

```
contracts.Should().NotContain(new Contract() { Id = id2, Name = "B" });
```

Effectively given a collection containing an unknown number of items, I want to ensure that; it contains a number of specific items, and that it doesn't contain a number of specific items.

Can this be achieved using the functions provided by FluentAssertions?

As a side note, I don't want to override `object.Equals` for the reasons discussed here. [Should I be using IEquatable to ease testing of factories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988487/should-i-be-using-iequatable-to-ease-testing-of-factories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does use the `object.Equals` as far as I can tell from documentation and my experience using the framework.

In scenarios like this I tend to use an expression predicate as referenced in [the collections documentation for v3.0 and higher](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#collections).

The following example shows how to make sure that collection contains only specific `Contract` objects and also assert that the collection doesn't contain a specific object.

```
[TestMethod]
public void FluentAssertions_Should_Validate_Collections() {
    //Arrange
    var id1 = Guid.NewGuid();
    var id2 = Guid.NewGuid();

    var list = new List<Contract>{
        new Contract() { Id = id1, Name = "A" },
        new Contract() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "B"}
    };

    var factoryMock = new Mock<IContractFactory>();
    factoryMock.Setup(m => m.BuildContracts()).Returns(list);
    var factory = factoryMock.Object;

    //Act
    var contracts = factory.BuildContracts();

    //Assert
    contracts.Should()
        .HaveCount(list.Count)
        .And.Contain(c => c.Id == id1 && c.Name == "A")
        .And.NotContain(c => c.Id == id2 && c.Name == "B");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override your contract `Equals` which will then be used and your Unit test should pass happily. 
If you're using random Guids it might be an issue, but it seems like you're using a predefined one.

Give the following a try:

```
protected bool Equals(Contract other)
{
    return Id.Equals(other.Id) && string.Equals(Name, other.Name);
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
    return Equals((Contract) obj);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        return (Id.GetHashCode()*397) ^ (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

and as you can see, it passes the test:
[image]

Comment: +1 and thanks for the suggestion. However this isnt really the answer I want, I used to override equals and just use a standard `Assert.IsTrue(contracts.Contains(...))`. But this had its own problems (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988487/should-i-be-using-iequatable-to-ease-testing-of-factories). I am hoping to use FluentAssertions to avoid overriding Equals.

Comment: Interesting link ... I'm sure you'll figure something out. I'll keep an eye on the post to see how it evolves :). BTW, have you given "[shouldly](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly)" a run ? I'm not sure what's its default behavior, but it might work the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to [Nkosi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi) answer, you could still use `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` by building the expecation.

Comment: Do you mean like `Should().Contain(c => c.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(contract1))`? Not sure how to get that to work as `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` doesn't have a return value. Not quite what you mean by "building the expecation". Thanks

Comment: Just create a collection with the `Contract` instances as you expect them and pass that as an expectation to `ShouldBeEquivalentTo`. If you care about a strict order, you can even use the `options => options.WithStrictOrdering`'

Comment: What about if if the collection contains other `Contracts` I don't care about? I.e. the collection contains 100 items, I want to make sure that it contains 2 specific items, and doesn't contain 1 specific item.