# Is there a better way to compare two objects partially then brute force?

Tags: c#, class

I've got a class called Account. After getting data from a webserver and a database, I want to compare the objects from the two sources in specific fields.

To do this, I wrote the  following:

```
public class Account2 : Account
{
    public bool Equals(Account acc)
    {
        if (acc.AccountNumber != this.AccountNumber)
            return false;
        if (acc.Name != this.Name)
            return false;
        if (acc.Address1_Line1 != this.Address1_Line1)
            return false;
        if (acc.Address1_PostalCode != this.Address1_PostalCode)
            return false;
        if (acc.Address1_City != this.Address1_City)
            return false;
        if (acc.PrimaryContactId.Id != this.PrimaryContactId.Id)
            return false;
        if (acc.OwnerId.Id != this.OwnerId.Id)
            return false;
        if (acc.Address1_Name != this.Address1_Name)
            return false;
        if (acc.Address1_Country != this.Address1_Country)
            return false;
        if (acc.Fax != this.Fax)
            return false;
        if (acc.Telephone1 != this.Telephone1)
            return false;
        if (acc.Telephone2 != this.Telephone2)
            return false;
        if (acc.Telephone3 != this.Telephone3)
            return false;
        if (acc.EMailAddress1 != this.EMailAddress1)
            return false;
        if (acc.EMailAddress2 != this.EMailAddress2)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

I thought about using attributes on the properties and do a loop over all to determine which I should compare. The problem is I dont have access to the base Account-class.
The main issue is when adding another class. I have to do this for 5 other ones which really is a lot to type. Additionally its hard to maintain if I add another field.

Is there a better way to do this comparison?

Comment: Have you tried this http://www.nuget.org/packages/CompareNETObjects

Comment: Also please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506096/comparing-object-properties-in-c-sharp

Comment: I tried using it. But I get the following error:  
"Cannot compare objects with a non integer indexer for object xxx "
And I dont think I can fix this.

Comment: Which one you have used the `CompareNetObjects` or the snippet in the SO answer.

Comment: The "Basic usage"-example from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/754435/Compare-NET-Objects-Tutorial

Comment: you could try omitting that non integer indexer from the comparison or add a custom comparer for that . Check the configuartion for CompareNetObjects