# Dictionary.ContainsKey return False, but a want True

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

```
namespace Dic
{
public class Key
{
    string name;
    public Key(string n) { name = n; }
}

class Program
{
    static string Test()
    {
        Key a = new Key("A");
        Key b = new Key("A");
        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Key, int> d = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Key, int>();
        d.Add(a, 1);
        return d.ContainsKey(b).ToString();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(Test());
    }
}
}
```

What should I change to get true?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You want true - but a and b are different objects.

You need to override GetHashCode and Equals on class Key

```
public class Key
{
    string name;
    public Key(string n) { name = n; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (name == null) return 0;
        return name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Key other = obj as key;
        return other != null && other.name == this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, if `Key` is truly that simple, you could define it as a `struct`.

Comment: Why do I even bother answering these questions. Everyone beats me to it by several minutes :)

Comment: GetHashCode should return an `int` in the declaration ;)

Comment: @Toby and how would the struct thing help with this? Elaborate please

Comment: @Galilyou: I think Toby's referring to the fact that `ValueType.Equals` by default compares structs by checking each of their fields. It does so using reflection, however, so performance is compromised. Overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` is generally a better approach when the intention is to use a type as a key in a dictionary (in my opinion).

Answer (score 10):

It would probably help if you override Key.GetHashCode and Key.Equals.

In `Key`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var k = obj as Key;
    if (k != null)
    {
        return this.name == k.name;
    }
    return base.Equals(obj);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.name.GetHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you do not have the ability to override equality operators/Equals/GetHashCode as others have mentioned (as in, you do not control the source code of the object), you can provide an `IEqualityComparer<Key>` implementation in the constructor of the dictionary to perform your equality checks.

```
class KeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Key>
{
    public bool Equals(Key x, Key y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Key obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

As it stands, your Key is a reference object, so equality is only determined on reference unless you tell the world (or the dictionary) otherwise.

Comment: Note: Of course, to have such an implementation, the members you wish to compare on must be externally accessible, they cannot be private.

Answer (score 7):

Overriding a class' GetHashCode and Equals methods so that it will work properly in a dictionary is not a very good approach.  The way a dictionary behaves should be an implementation detail of the dictionary, not of whatever class is being used as a key.  You'll get into trouble when you want to use the class in different dictionaries with different behavior.  Or if you don't have access to the class source code.

A better mouse trap is to give the dictionary its own comparer.  For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var d = new Dictionary<Key, int>(new MyComparer());
        d.Add(new Key("A"), 1);
        Console.WriteLine(d.ContainsKey(new Key("a")));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Key> {
        public bool Equals(Key x, Key y) {
            return string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name, true) == 0;
        }
        public int GetHashCode(Key obj) {
            return obj.Name.ToUpper().GetHashCode();
        }
    }
    public class Key {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Key(string name) { Name = name; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use your own classes as dictionary keys, you should override GetHashCode and Equals. Otherwise it will use the memory address to check for equality.

```
    public class Key
    {
        string name;
        public Key(string n) { name = n; }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return name.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = obj as Key;
            if( other == null )
                return false;

            return name == other.name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: just need to verify in get GetHashCode that name is not null

Comment: Yes, of course. Depends if he want's null keys, but it's a bug as of now :)

Answer (score 1):

you problem is that

```
new Key("A").Equals(new Key("A"))==false.
```

and

```
new Key("A").GetHashCode()!=new Key("A").GetHashCode()
```

fix that and it should work I think.  To fix it override the Equals method and check if the name values are the same.  You should also override GetHashCode if you are overriding Equals.

Comment: To be precise, fixing `Equals` will *not* change the behaviour of `==` neither `!=`. These would have to be overridden as well (highly recommended!) but this isn’t required for `Dictionary`.

Comment: @Konrad, Microsoft [advises against](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx) overriding == for mutable types like Key.

Comment: @Matthew: to be honest, I stopped heeding Microsoft’s coding guidelines quite some time ago when I noticed that they churned out lots of baseless, unjustified advice that contradicted my experience. In this particular case, it *can* actually be justified (but isn’t! Why?) but I still think the advice is backwards. It should rather be: make objects immutable if possible. If not, don’t override `Equals` either. And yes, that means such objects can’t be stored in Dictionaries. So what? Python has the same restriction with very similar semantics and it works well.

Comment: @Matthew: (cont’d) Making `Equals` and `operator ==` inconsistent violates [POLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_surprise) and doesn’t really serve a purpose. Had they supported operator overloading from the start and allowed virtual operators, this whole artificial dichotomy would never have arisen and `Equals` would never have existed. The only reason for its existence in the first place is that operators cannot be virtual in .NET.

Comment: I think this one has a quite simple reason.  Programmers expect that the == result for a pair of objects won't change.  For programmers familiar with C, Java, or non-overridden C#, this is the least surprising outcome.

Comment: @Matthew: I would contest that assumption. Programmers (beginners) are expecting side effects everywhere (immutable strings seem to be a major stumbling block, as evidenced by the questions about the return value of `String.Replace`). I also don’t see how this assumption would be different for `Equals`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to override Equals and GetHashCode methods of your  Key class.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Override Equals, Get Hash Code, and the '==' Operator.**

The Key class must override `Equals` in order for the Dictionary to detect if they are the same.  The default implementation is going to check references only.

Here:

```
        public bool Equals(Key other)
        {
            return this == other;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null || !(obj is Key))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return this.Equals((Key)obj);
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Key k1, Key k2)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(k1, k2))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if ((object)k1 == null || (object)k2 == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return k1.name == k2.name;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Key k1, Key k2)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(k1, k2))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if ((object)k1 == null || (object)k2 == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return k1.name != k2.name;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.name == null ? 0 : this.name.GetHashCode();
        }
```

**2. If Possible, use a struct.**

You should use a struct for immutable datatypes like this, since they are passed by value.  This would mean that you coulnd't accidentally munge two different values into the same key.

Comment: This code isn’t safe (NRE in `GetHashCode` for one thing) and somewhat longer than it needs to be due to unnecessary code duplications. For a non-redundant implementation, check [my write-up on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104158/what-is-best-practice-for-comparing-two-instances-of-a-reference-type/104309#104309).

Comment: Alright, I fixed the errors, and I +1'd your implementation on the other question.

Answer (score 0):

they have the same values internally but a != b as they are 2 different variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods of your Key class. In your case you could compare based on the key's name (or on any other unique property if your class is more complex).

```
public class Key {
    string name;
    public Key(string n) { name = n; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        Key k = obj as Key;
        if (k == null)
            return false;
        return name.Equals(k.name);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you will need to override GetHashCode and Equals on the Key class.

Without doing that, you get the default implementation of both. Which results in the hashcode for a and b to be most likely not the same (I don't know how what the default implementation looks like), and a to be definitely not equal to b (the default Equals() implementation checks reference equality).

In your case, assuming "name" is not a null, it could be implemented as

```
   public class Key
   {
        string name;
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
             return name.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
              return false;
            }

            Key objAsKey = obj as Key;
            if (objAsKey == null)
            {
              return false;
            }

            return this.name.Equals(objAsKey.Name);
        }
    }
```

Whether this is a satisfactory hash is a different story, but it shows the principle, nevertheless.

Comment: And what if `name` is `null`? Boom. Crash. Bang.

Comment: That's why I said, and I quote: "...In your case, assuming "name" is not a null..."

Answer (score -1):

ContainsKey in this case is comparing Key as objects and checking to see if the objects themselves are the same -- they are not. You need to implement IComparable or override Key.Equals or something along those lines to get it to do what you want.

Comment: Careful – `Dictionary` is implemented in terms of a hash map so (unlike `SortedDictionary` and `SortedList`) implementing `IComparable` has *no* effect whatsoever.