# "the given key was not present in the dictionary" error when using a self-defined class as key

Tags: c#

I've got code like this:

```
if (CounterForEachRelatedTagDict.Select(x => x.Key).Contains(tag.Key))
   CounterForEachRelatedTagDict[tag.Key] += tag.Value;
```

Is it possible that the IF statement returns true, at the same time `CounterForEachRelatedTagDict[tag.Key]` returns "the given key was not present in the dictionary" error? `tag` is a `KeyValuePair<MyClass,int>`.

`CounterForEachRelatedTagDict` is initiated like this:

```
Dictionary<MyClass, int> CounterForEachRelatedTagDict = new Dictionary<MyType, int>();
```

`MyClass` is like this

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

It seems almost unreasonable to me...

Comment: What is tag2 object - edit: looks like that was a typo.

Comment: @frinkenstein789 MyType is a class, maybe I should change it into MyClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use your type as a dictionary key you should override two methods: `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

By default (if you'll not override `GetHashCode`) every object of your type (even with the same field values) will return unique value. This means that you'll be able to find only exactly the same "reference" that you'll put into your dictionary. Consider following two types: `MyType1` that not overrides `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, and MyType2 that do:

```
class MyType1
{
  public MyType1(int id, string name) {Id = id; Name = name;}
  public int Id {get; private set;}
  public string Name {get; private set;}
}


internal class MyType2
{
    public MyType2(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    bool Equals(MyType2 other)
    {
        return Id == other.Id && string.Equals(Name, other.Name);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((MyType2) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (Id*397) ^ Name.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}

var d1 = new Dictionary<MyType1, int>();
d1[new MyType1(1, "1")] = 1;
d1[new MyType1(1, "1")]++; // will throw withKeyNotFoundException

var d2 = new Dictionary<MyType2, int>();
d1[new MyType2(1, "1")] = 1;
d1[new MyType2(1, "1")]++; // Ok, we'll find appropriate record in dictionary
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I would just like to know: what does `(Id*397) ^ Name.GetHashCode()`mean? Why it has to be 397? Btw, in my case the Id is a Guid.

Comment: Actually this code was generated by Resharper but the whole point of this stuff is to create more robust hash function, because default implementation like Id.GetHashCode() ^ Name.GetHashCode() can give collisions very often. In your case (using Guid) this is not the case, but with integer fields this is a good option to prevent collisions.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `Equal` and `GetHashCode` methods are out of sync for `MyType`.

When you use `CounterForEachRelatedTagDict.Select(x => x.Key).Contains(tag.Key)` you're performing a linear search through all of the keys using `Equals` to compare what you're searching for to each key.

When you use `ContainsKey` in `Dictionary`, the indexer, or one of a number of other methods for finding a key you first hash the key using `GetHashCode` and then it only uses `Equals` to find which of the (hopefully very few objects) are identical within that bucket.

What's happening is that you have two object for which `first.Equals(second)` returns true, but for which `GetHashCode` returns two different values.  It's very important that, when using objects as keys in a `Dictionary`, any two objects for which `Equals` returns `true` must also return the same integer for `GetHashCode`.  Ideally different objects should return different hash codes whenever possible, but it's not always possible (different objects with the same hash code are called "collisions").

Note that this method of finding keys, while it does force you to ensure all objects used as keys have sensible implementations of `GetHashCode` (the default implementation that comes from `object` is rarely appropriate) this algorithm is * extraordinary* efficient (with efficient hashing algorithms) which is what makes it worthwhile.  Using `ContainsKey`, or the indexer of the dictionary, is much, much faster than going through each key and comparing it, which is what your `Select` code needs to do to avoid using `GetHashCode`.

So, to answer your question, yes, it's quite possible for `CounterForEachRelatedTagDict.Select(x => x.Key).Contains(tag.Key)` to find an item while the indexer can't.

Answer (score 2):

First:You can use the `ContainsKey` method instead of that Linq Query.

Second: You must override the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` for `MyType`. that's the way that Dictionary look up and compare the keys.

Check out these similar questions: [Dictionary.ContainsKey return False, but a want True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014945/dictionary-containskey-return-false-but-a-want-true), [Using an object as a generic Dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634826/using-an-object-as-a-generic-dictionary-key-in-net)