# C# equality checking

Tags: c#, equality

*What's your approach on writing equality checks for the `structs` and `classes` you create?*

**1)** Does the "full" equality checking require that much of boilerplate code (like `override Equals`, `override GetHashCode`, generic `Equals`, `operator==`, `operator!=`)?

**2)** Do you specify explicitly that your classes model the `IEquatable<T>` interface?

**3)** Do I understand correctly, that there is no actual way to automatically apply `Equals` overrides, when I invoke something like `a == b` and I always have to implement both the `Equals` and `operator==` members?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're right, this is a lot of boiler-plate code, and you need to implement everything separately.

I would recommend:

- If you're going to implement value equality at all, override `GetHashCode` and `Equals(object)` - creating overloads for == and implementing `IEquatable<T>` without doing that could result in very unexpected behaviour
- I would always implement `IEquatable<T>` if you're overriding `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode`
- I only overload the == operator more rarely
- Implementing equality correctly for unsealed classes is tricky, and can still produce surprising/undesirable results. If you need equality for types in a hierarchy, implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` expressing the comparison you're interested in.
- Equality for mutable types is usually a bad idea, as two objects can be equal and then unequal later... if an object is mutated (in an equality-affecting way) after it's been used as a key in a hash table, you won't be able to find it again.
- Some of the boiler-plate is slightly different for structs... but like Marc, I very rarely write my own structs.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
using System;

public sealed class Foo : IEquatable<Foo>
{
    private readonly string name;
    public string Name { get { return name; } }

    private readonly int value;
    public int Value { get { return value; } }

    public Foo(string name, int value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return Equals(other as Foo);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 31 + (name == null ? 0 : name.GetHashCode());
        hash = hash * 31 + value;
        return hash;
    }

    public bool Equals(Foo other)
    {
        if ((object) other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return name == other.name && value == other.value;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Foo left, Foo right)
    {
        return object.Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Foo left, Foo right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}
```

And yes, that's a heck of a lot of boilerplate, very little of which changes between implementations :(

The implementation of `==` is *slightly* less efficient than it might be, as it will call through to `Equals(object)` which needs to do the dynamic type check... but the alternative is even more boiler-plate, like this:

```
public static bool operator ==(Foo left, Foo right)
{
    if ((object) left == (object) right)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // "right" being null is covered in left.Equals(right)
    if ((object) left == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return left.Equals(right);
}
```

Comment: 2 minor suggestions for the second code block: 1) Shouldn't you move `(object) left == (object) right` from `==` to generic `Equals`? So that gives the speed (of course it depends, but assuming the worst case) checking of reference equality even for generic `Equals` method? 2) you dont need the second null check `(object) right == null` in `==` as you essentially do that in generic `Equals`. See my post..

Comment: @nawfal: I don't think there's much point in doing it in the generic `Equals` case - it's going to be quick anyway in the cases where it *is* true, and for the cases where it *isn't* true, it's adding an extra check for no benefit. As for the null part - that would require the dynamic type check again. Yes, you could argue for both - but I'm happy enough with what I wrote two years ago...

Comment: @nawfal: Um, you're right - there'd be no dynamic check there. I'll remove the "right" part here...

Comment: @JonSkeet its so frustrating to write this boilerplate code over and over when making a mistake is so easy in these things. Thankfully snippets can help in this regard! I would have tried to get away by writing a generic abstract base class that does the job (I know the potential dangers, but if I can manage, then thats ok) to be derived by base classes, but that limits the derived classes from inheriting from another base class.. Just saying..

Answer (score 6):

I rarely do anything special for classes; for most regular objects referential equality works fine.

I even more rarely write a `struct`; but since structs represent *values* it is usually appropriate to provide equality etc. This would usually involve everything; Equals, ==, != and `IEquatable<T>` (since this avoids boxing in scenarios using `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`.

The boilerplate isn't usually too problematic, but IIRC tools like resharper can help here.

Yes, it is advisable to keep Equals and == in sync, and this needs to be done explicitely.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to implement operator== for a==b . 
As I like my data in dictionaries sometimes I override GetHashCode.

 Next I implement Equals (as an unmentioned standard ... this is because there is no constraint for equality when using generics) and specify implementing IEquatable. Since I am going to do this I might as well point my == and != implementations to Equals. :)

Answer (score 0):

See [What is "Best Practice" For Comparing Two Instances of a Reference Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104158/what-is-best-practice-for-comparing-two-instances-of-a-reference-type)

You can avoid boiler plate code (hope C#/VS team brings something easy for developers in their next iteration) with the help of a snippet, [here is one such..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/104309/661933)