# What is the difference between using class and struct with Dictionary.ContainsKey()?

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, struct, c#-2.0

Below is a sample of my dictionary definition.  When I define `DicKeys` as a `class`, `ContainsKey()` doesn't work.  If I change `DicKeys` to a `struct`, it works properly.

Why does `ContainsKey()` work differently for a `class` than it does for a `struct`?

```
Dictionary<DicKeys, DicVals> aDic = new Dictionary<DicKeys, DicVals>();

// original version as below
public Class DicKeys 
{
   public EnKey1 DicKeyItem1,
   public EnKey2 DicKeyItem2,
}

// revised version as below
public struct DicKeys
{
   public EnKey1 DicKeyItem1,
   public EnKey2 DicKeyItem2,
}

// common parts of code below
public enum EnKey1 
{
   A1,
   A2,
}

public enum EnKey2 
{
   B11,
   B12,
}

DicKeys aDicKey = new DicKeys();
// assigned value to aDicKey obj here;

if (aDic.ContainsKey(aDicKey ) == true)  
{
 // do some thing here
 // If I defined as 'class', it doesn't hit here.
 // Updated to 'struct', it hit here.
}
```

Comment: @Xaqron, sorry for my mistypeing, it should be `aDicKey`.

Comment: not get that doubt but public Class DicKeys , Class C should be c...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you haven't shown where you're populating the dictionary or what `sfTKey` is... but I strongly suspect it's because you haven't overridden `Equals` or `GetHashCode` in `DicKeys`.

By default, classes use *reference identity* for equality - in other words, two key references will only compare as equal if they refer to the exact same object. You can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to provide equality based on the *contents* of the objects though. Value types (structs) automatically use value-based equality, but I certainly *wouldn't* recommend using a mutable struct as you've got here. (I wouldn't recommend using public fields at all, to be honest.)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420901/c-equality-checking) for an example of the kind of thing you might do in `Equals` and `GetHashCode` - and some other members you may want to provide on types which have value-based equality.

Comment: Sorry, `sfTKey` should be `aDicKey`. It was validated and assigned successfully for my case. I am sure that it caused by the Key words of `class` or `struct` based on my practic.

Comment: @Nano: Changing the name of the variable doesn't make any difference. You still haven't shown where you're populating the dictionary.

Comment: Yes, it din't do any overridden operations for `Equals` or `GetHashCode` in my completed code. I would step into it. Thanks.