# I have 2 dimensional array and I want to returns true if there are 3 (or more) elements next to each other in one row,

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

My problem is the if statement doesn't work and I don't know how to solve this question when I run the code always gives me a row score that's mean that there are three elements or more that are the same however this is not correct.
extra details hereunder about the question

I have 2-dimensional array and I want to return true if there are 3 (or more) elements next to each other in one row,
this is the question:
the method returns true if there
are 3 (or more) symbols next to each other in one row, otherwise it returns false.
To determine ‘3 in a row’ check all rows (one by one), and in each row remember
the ‘current candy’ and set a counter to 1. If the next candy is the same (as the
previous one) then increase the counter, otherwise reset the counter to 1 and
set the ‘current candy’ again. If the counter becomes 3 then you can return true.
→ Check if there are (>=) 3 symbols adjacent in one row.

This is my Method

how can I improve it?

```
bool ScoreRowPresent(RegularCandies[,] playingField)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < playingField.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                int counter = 1;
                RegularCandies candies = RegularCandies.JellyBean;

                for (int x = 1; x < playingField.GetLength(1); x++)
                {
                    if (candies==playingField[i,0])
                    {
                        counter++;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        counter = 1;
                        candies = playingField[i, x];
                    }
                    if (counter >= 3)
                    {
                        return true;

                    }

                }

            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Are you experiencing problems with your code, or did you mean to ask on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Xerillio
 yes my code doesnt work, and I don't know where I made a mistake thats why Im sharing my code so that someone can help me and telling me where I made a mistake !

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add some details about what the problem is. Are you getting exceptions? Are you getting some unexpected behaviour that you could explain?

Comment: @Mayez, can you share the RegularCandies declaration?

Comment: On first look , i belive this link will help you , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400028/comparing-two-instances-of-a-class

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
bool ScoreRowPresent(RegularCandies[,] playingField)
{
    for (var row = 0; row < playingField.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        var candyToCount = playingField[row, 0];

        var counter = 1;

        for (var column = 1; column < playingField.GetLength(1); column++)
        {
            if (playingField[row, column] == candyToCount)
            {
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                counter = 1;
                candyToCount = playingField[row, column];
            }

            if (counter >= 3)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: What's the purpose of adding `maxAdjacentCandyCount`? `counter` should be enough: `if (counter >= 3) return true;`

Comment: @Xerillio you are right! Thank you for warning me. Locally I was trying out an approach when the number of max adjacent columns returned, but I copied the wrong code (fixed now, answer updated).