# Operator overloading giving error

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class named Point that overloading "==" and "!=" operators to compare two Point object. How can I compare my Point object with "null", this a problem because when I call ==  or != operator with null a problem inside Equals method. Please open a console application and see what I want to say.How can  I fix it.

```
public class Point
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }


        public static bool operator == (Point p1,Point p2)
        {
            return p1.Equals(p2);
        }

        public static bool operator != (Point p1, Point p2)
        {
            return !p1.Equals(p2);
        }


        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            Point other = obj as Point;

            //problem is here calling != operator and this operator calling  this method again
            if (other != null)
            {
                if (this.X == other.X && this.Y == other.Y)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Parameter is not a point");
            }
        }
    }

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point p1 = new Point { X = 9, Y = 7 };
            Point p2 = new Point { X = 5, Y = 1 };

            p1.X = p2.X;
            p1.Y = p2.Y;

            bool b1=p1==p2;

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check for `null` in the operators and don't throw. Comparing a value against null is definitely *not* an exceptional case.

Comment: What error are you getting? Because in my eyes your code will cause an infinite loop?

Comment: thanks the problem is solved by Lasse V. Karlsen

Comment: Pardon the shameless plug but since this question is so damned difficult I’ll just refer to my [existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/104309/1968) which shows the One Right Way™ of implementing equality operators in .NET, and I’ll add that you should also strongly consider implementing the [`IEquatable` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx) in your class: that’s what it’s there for, and people rudely ignore it. :-( Oh, and when overriding `Equals`, you **must** override `GetHashCode` as well. Otherwise chaos ensues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ReferenceEquals` to check for `null`:

```
if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
```

Having said that, `Equals` should generally not throw an exception if it encounters an unknown object type, it should just return `false`, thus here is the method I would write:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Point other = obj as Point;

    if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        return false;

    return (this.X == other.X && this.Y == other.Y);
}
```

An additional problem is that your operators will throw an exception if you compare `null` against something, as you can't invoke the instance method on a `null` reference.

Thus, here is the full class I would've written:

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }


    public static bool operator == (Point p1,Point p2)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(p1, p2)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(p1, null)) return false;
        return p1.Equals(p2);
    }

    public static bool operator != (Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return !(p1 == p2);
    }

    public bool Equals(Point other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            return false;

        return (this.X == other.X && this.Y == other.Y);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Point other = obj as Point;
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            return false;
        return Equals(other);
    }
}
```

Comment: but if  the parameter object is a different object type like Car there is a probem.  other.X cause an exception

Comment: also I can't compare my Point object with null anywhere.

Comment: No, because `obj as Point` will then return `null` and then the method will return `false`. It will never try to compare `X` and `Y ` from a `Car` since it is not a `Point`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "also I can't compare my Point object with null anywhere.".

Comment: when I  write this code in program.cs Point p= new Point(); if(p==null) what will happen.

Comment: I am not going to respond to any more comments where you don't say clearly what you mean and what you observe. When you write this code in program.cs, then *what*? What happens? What did you expect?

Comment: Sorry my English is bad, but your code working correctly there is not problem thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You should not throw an exception at:

```
        if (other != null)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Parameter is not a point");
        }
```

You can read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/336aedhh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx to see how `Equals()` is properly implemented.

Comment: It may be a bad idea to use other!= null, since you will use the overlaod for != . Better user ReferenceEquals

Comment: There is no real advantage in using `ReferenceEquals(ref, null)` over `ref == null`. IMHO the second one is easier to read. Anyway, my intention was to give an answer, why the aksers `==` operator fails. Nevertheless you should stick to the guidelines from Microsoft to ensure `Equals` works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Handling equality in C# can be tricky and it's easy to fall into pit traps like you've encountered here.

I always follow the same pattern when dealing with equality, be it in value types or in reference types (except the `null` checking obviously): implement a static private helper method that takes care of all possibilities, and let all equality checks invoke this method.

So, in your case, I'd do the following:

***UPDATE***: Fixed a typo, `equals` should be `private`, not `public`.

```
 private static bool equals(Point p1, Point p2)
 {
     if (object.ReferenceEquals(p1, p2))
         return true;

     if (object.ReferenceEquals(p1, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(p2, null))
         return false;

     return p1.X == p2.X && p1.Y == p2.Y;
 }
```

Ok, so what are we doing here?

1. We first check to see if both objects have equal references. If
   thats the case, then they have to be equal as they are the same
   object. Note that this takes care of the `null == null` case.
2. Then we check to see if any of the two arguments is equal to `null`.
   If they are, then we know that `p1` and `p2` are not equal.

   To see if the arguments are equal to `null` we use the satic method
   `bool object.ReferenceEquals(,)` to avoid the issue you are having
   which is calling again your equality implementation.
3. Last, we now know we have two non null `Point` arguments so we go
   ahead and implement the specific equality logic of two `Point` objects.

With this simple method we have dealt with all possible equality checks in our class. Now we simply have to invoke this method from all possible equality methods and operators:

```
public static bool operator ==(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return Point.equals(p1, p2);
}

public static bool operator !=(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return !Point.equals(p1, p2);
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return Point.equals(this, obj as Point);
}
```

Additionaly, you should implement the `IEquatable<Point>` interface which is pretty straightforward. This is specially relevant when dealing with *value types* as you avoid boxing conversions when performing equality checks:

```
public bool Equals(Point p)
{
    return Point.equals(this, p);
}
```

And last but not least, you are overriding the `Equals` method and the `==` and `!=` operators so you should also override `int GetHashCode()` in a way consistent with your equality implementation: if `p1 == p2` then `p1.GetHashCode()` *must* equal `p1.GetHashCode()` (Note, that this does not mean that if `p1 != p2`, `p1.GetHashCode()` must not equal `p2.GetHashCode()`):

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.X ^ this.Y;
}
```

Hope this small guideline helps.

Comment: Your solution is very good thanks.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it implements `Equals(Object)` in terms of `Equals(Object, Object)` (well, actually, confusingly, `equals`), which is overridden. But the `Object` class in .NET is designed to handle this exactly the other way round: that is, the pre-defined static [`Object.Equals(Object, Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is implemented in terms of `Object.Equals(Object)`, and works perfectly well when the latter is overridden. So that’s the route implementors should take. That way, they override one fewer method.

Comment: @KonradRudolph And where have I done something different? My static `equals(Point, Point)` is a *private implementation detail* of my class; I fail to see where the issue with `object.Equals(object, object)` is. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ooops, now I see what you are saying. Thats a typo! `equals` should be private. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @InBetween Actually, I was mainly confused by `equals` vs `Equals`. However, your code still has one minor flaw, a performance bug: your `equals` tests whether the first argument is `null`. However, `Point.Equals(Object)` has already done that. implicitly. The test is thus redundant but your code still needs it for different code paths. This isn’t ideal. It’s arguably acceptable of course but I would personally avoid such redundancy in core functionality: equality comparison is potentially used a lot, in hot code paths.

Comment: @KonradRudolph True, that is a fair point, but unless I have good reasons that indicate that the few nanoseconds I waste performing in some equality checks an unecessary `null` check is not allowing my code meet my performance goals I prefer the simplicity of this approach where you have all the logic in one place and not sprinkled across several methods.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I forgot to point out that I use this pattern mainly with `IComarable<T>` where the amount of public entry points is rather big (around 10 if I remember correctly). In this case, having all the logic focused in one single method is handy unless you run into specific performance issues (to be honest, I have yet to find a case where this code is the performance bottleneck).

Comment: @InBetween Of course you shouldn’t repeat the logic, I agree. The correct way to implement this with minimal code duplication (and `IEquatable`, which is the equality comparison equivalent of `IComparable`) is highlighted in an old answer I wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/a/104309/1968

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj != null && obj is Point)
    {
       Point other = (Point)obj;
       if (this.X == other.X && this.Y == other.Y)
       {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```